# Can I put Facebook's Like button on my web page even though I'm using XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Tags: xhtml-transitional

I would like to add the Facebook Like button to my homepage at http://www.theorganizationindex.com but notice that Facebook seems to require that I use i-frame, XFBML, or HTML5. Will the Like button work if I am using XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Comment: AFIK the social networks don't care for valid html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Facebook API is based off of Javascript and should not matter if you're using any of those items you listed. I set up a recipe web site and used both Twitter and Facebook API add-ons and it worked just fine. Let me know if you're having issues and you can email me your source code if it's too much to post here and I can implement the FB-Like button API script for you. There is a javascript include that is hosted off of Facebooks website you must have in your head or it will not work.